# Postgres update first record in JSON column for all records

Tags: postgresql

I'm using postgres 9.6.1.

I have an "orders" table that has a column "orderData" that is type JSON.

**What each record in the orderData column currently looks like:**

```
[{"orderId":1}, {"orderId":2}, {"orderId":3}]
```

I'm trying to write a sql query that adds a key to the first order object in each array.

**What each record in the orderData column should look like after query:**

```
[{"orderId":1, "isFirstOrder": true}, {"orderId":2}, {"orderId":3}]
```

**NOT WORKING ATTEMPT:**

```
WITH order AS (
  SELECT orderData
  FROM orders
  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(c) s
  WHERE i = 1
)
UPDATE order
SET c = JSON_MODIFY(c, 'isFirstOrder', 'true');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where [in the Postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/index.html) did you find  `cross apply` or `openjson()` or `json_modify()`?

Comment: I did not find it in the docs.  I found it in another stackoverflow answer when I couldn't figure out how to do this from the pg docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=b5bb5ffab74fb0df77efc38f9b8b5f66)

```
UPDATE orders
SET c = jsonb_set(c, '{0}', c -> 0 || '{"isFirstOrder": true}');
```

1. `c -> 0` gets the first element of your array
2. `||` adds the new attribute
3. `jsonb_set` rewrites the elements if they exists whereas `{0}` locates the rewriting position within the array

[Postgres JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

---

For type `json` there's no function `json_set`. So you have to do a bit of casting around your `json` data into `jsonb` and the final result back into `json`:

```
UPDATE orders
SET c = jsonb_set(c::jsonb, '{0}', c::jsonb -> 0 || '{"isFirstOrder": true}')::json
```

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=de603b463150512d70c1b011db275186)

Comment: Fiddle is perfect.  But it's failing when I try to run it in my db.  "ERROR:  function jsonb_set(json, unknown, text) does not exist".  Possible issue with the data i have stored in this column?

Comment: Updated my answer for type json.