# How to extract paths for JSONb data editing from ".**" query?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a deep tree like `{id: "123", val: "bla", data: [{id: "223", other_val: "", data: [...]}, ...]}` and I do not know how deep is the key I am searching for (say "`other_val_x`"). I can [query it](https://github.com/obartunov/sqljsondoc/blob/master/jsonpath.md#jsonpath-functions) (meaning find and read value).

Yet I need `$.**.other_val_x` to turn into a set capable query. A query I could feed to `UPDATE` (`jsonb_set`)to update its value.

So in other words I want to get from `.**` path to editable (json_setable) objects - full path to where data resides to be able to call json_set. I need it in order to edit a heavily nested object in a deep tree with variable depth.

So how one could get paths that allow object editing from `.**` operator related functions?

Comment: JSON objects in PostgreSQL are as immutable as all other data. You have to create a new JSON and use that in an `UPDATE` SQL statement.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53157922/postgres-update-first-record-in-json-column-for-all-records) seems to contradict that idea.

Comment: `jsonb_set` creates a new JSON object with a different value at a specific path. It does not modify the existing JSON. If that is what you want, please tell us which attribute you want to set different.

Comment: Ok - Update via setting? To do that one needs paths in another format than ".**" and that is the biggest problem for me.

Comment: Which attribute of the JSON in your question do you want to modify?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: that is my main point - I have a deep tree like `{id: "123", val: "bla", data: [{id: "223", other_val: "", data: [...]}, ...]}` and I do not know how deep is the key I am searching for (say "`other_val_x`"). So I eed `$.**.other_val_x` to turn into query. That query I want to feed to `UPDATE` to update its value

Comment: If that is possible, it will at least be quite difficult. I can't think of a way offhand.